# Написать код на питоне

Tags: python

Написать программу которая записывает введённое слово наоборот и все символы должны быть в нижнем регистре

Comment: Напишите. В чем вопрос. Или вы размечтались что тут напишут ВМЕСТО вас? Так так и надо было писать.

Comment: как писать в нижнем регистре я понимаю а как перевернуть слово не очень понимаю

Comment: `s = 'hello'` -> `s[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Введенное слово в нижний регистр и наоборот. Куда записать, решайте.

```
input().lower()[::-1]
```